# Subtract sets so that rest of the similar multiple elements are retained in the result

Tags: r

For example, I have 2 chairs and one table in *set1* and 1 chair in *set2*.
I want to subtract *set2* from *set1* and want the result as `c("chair", "table")`

```
set1 <- c("chair", "chair", "table")
set2 <- c("chair")

setdiff(set1, set2)
```

gives `"table"`

Comment: `unique(c(set1, set2))` perhaps.

Comment: @David that won't work well if there are three chairs in `set1`.

Comment: @Arenburg, the problem with unique(c(set1, set2)) is if I have 3 chairs in set1 I do not get the desired result ("chair","chair", "table").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `vecsets` will perform set operations on vectors while retaining duplicates:

```
vecsets::vsetdiff( c("chair", "chair", "table"), c("chair") )
# [1] "chair" "table"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
set1 <- c("chair", "chair", "table")
set2 <- c("chair")

levels <- union(set1, set2)

set1 <- factor(set1, levels = levels)
set2 <- factor(set2, levels = levels)

rep(levels, table(set1) - table(set2))
#[1] "chair" "table"
```

Comment: can we make a function that will take set1 and set2 as arguments and give the result.

Comment: setsub <- function( x, y) { 
    levels <- union(x, y)
x <- factor(x, levels = levels)
y <- factor(y, levels = levels)

rep(levels, table(x) - table(y))
}
setsub(set1,set2)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use `make.unique` to make the names unique, and then use `%in%` to create a logical vector and index the original one, i.e.

```
set1[!make.unique(set1) %in% make.unique(set2)]
#[1] "chair" "table"
```

Or make it a function,

```
f1 <- function(vec1, vec2){
    vec1[!make.unique(vec1) %in% make.unique(vec2)]
}

f1(set1, set2)
```