# Non duplicate remove subsetting

Tags: r, subset

```
a <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B")
b <- c("A", "C", "A")
```

I want to subset `a` wrt to `b` such that the following set is obtained:-

```
("B"  "A"  "B")
```

Tradition subsetting results in removal of all the `"A"`s and `"C"`s from set `a`.
It removes duplicates also. I don't want them to be remove. For ex:- Set `b` has 2 `"A"`s and 1 `"C"`. So while subsetting `a` wrt `b` only two `"A"`s and one `"C"` should be removed from set `a`. And rest all the elements in `a` should remain even though they might be `"A"` or `"C"`.

I just want to know if there is a way of doing this in **R**.

Comment: might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672743/subtract-sets-so-that-rest-of-the-similar-multiple-elements-are-retained-in-the and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52941312/set-difference-between-two-vectors-with-duplicate-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy option is to use `vsetdiff` from package `vecsets`, i.e.,

```
vecsets::vsetdiff(a,b)
```

such that

```
> vecsets::vsetdiff(a,b)
[1] "B" "A" "B"
```

Comment: This is even more helpful. Will reduce a lot of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this :

```
#Count occurrences of `a`
a_count <- table(a)
#Count occurrences of `b`
b_count <- table(b)
#Subtract the count present in b from a 
a_count[names(b_count)] <- a_count[names(b_count)] - b_count

#Create a new vector of remaining values 
rep(names(a_count), a_count)
#[1] "A" "B" "B"
```

Comment: Thanks you. This will help a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using `tibble` and `dplyr`, you can do:

```
enframe(a) %>%
 transmute(name = value) %>%
 group_by(name) %>%
 mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
 left_join(enframe(table(b)), by = c("name" = "name")) %>%
 filter(ID > value | is.na(value)) %>%
 pull(name)

[1] "B" "A" "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
a <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B")
b <- c("A", "C", "A")

greedy_delete <- function(x, rmv) {
  for (i in rmv) {
    x <- x[-which(x == i)[1]]
  }
  x
}
greedy_delete(a, b)
#"B" "A" "B"
```